# How to remove strange string in generated index.html file after gulp build

Tags: build, gulp

I've got a build.js file, where I handle my gulp build. It looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
            path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
        ])
        .pipe($.minifyHtml({
            empty: true,
            spare: true,
            quotes: true
        }))
        .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
            module: 'wiCareNow',
            root: 'app'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function() {
    var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
    var partialsInjectOptions = {
        starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
        ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
        addRootSlash: false
    };

    var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

    return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
        .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.rev())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.minifyCss({ processImport: false }))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe($.revReplace())
        .pipe(htmlFilter)
        .pipe($.minifyHtml({
            empty: true,
            spare: true,
            quotes: true,
            conditionals: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
        .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
});

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
        .pipe($.flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function() {
    var fileFilter = $.filter(function(file) {
        return file.stat.isFile();
    });

    return gulp.src([
            path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
            path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss,ts}')
        ])
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

My build works fine, the only thing I would like to change is a strange postfix in my generated `index.html`:

[image]

At the beginning there wasn't the string, just `index.html`. But now I've got this string and would like to remove it from my generated file name. I found this issue, but have no idea what to do: [gulp/minify: index.html gets cryptic extension in file name, how to take advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758372/gulp-minify-index-html-gets-cryptic-extension-in-file-name-how-to-take-advanta)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.pipe($.rev())` to prevent static asset revisioning.